# Error from Omniauth using Facebook auth - Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm integrating Facebook with my app by following [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview), everything works fine until I try to login via Facebook.

Then I'm keep on getting this error

[image]

This is my Facebook app setup:

[image]

I've tried several different ways of changing the app domain by following several tutorials.

I've tried:

- leaving the app domain blank
- adding `localhost`
- adding `localhost:3000`

and none seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try setting up a facebook login product. Then under settings place  localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback under Valid OAuth redirect URIs. That's what got it for me.

Comment: hey @ArronG, sorry for the late reply, thanks and it worked